# How to run mypy plugin in PyCharm to inspect typing code?

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I managed to install the mypy plugin into PyCharm community IDE 2020.1. I also installed the `mypy` package through `conda install mypy`.

How do I run the mypy plugin in PyCharm to inspect my existing python code? I can't find any menu option to run mypy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the mypi plugins and mypi package, an extra window will appear on the bottom, next to the terminal. To scan, click on the green arrow.